# Enabling JSX support in PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3

Tags: javascript, pycharm, jsx

Everywhere I read about it, it says to go to Settings - Languages & Frameworks - JavaScript... But that's not even an alternative in the Settings dialog I see. I can only choose "Schemas and DTDs" or "IPython Notebook".

Is there JSX support at all in the Community Edition? If so, how do I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Preferences and search for JSX: [image]

Sourced from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/emmet-jsx.html

Note that I have the professional version and that help page does not mention the feature being excluded from the community edition.